# Install Location (Mac) for SQL Server JDBC Driver

Tags: python, sql-server, macos, jdbc, apache-spark-sql

I want to directly query SQL Server tables using Spark SQL via Python. I need to install the SQL Server driver, which I've download,

> ... to the directory where you want the driver installed and type tar
>   –xf sqljdbc__.tar.

(according to Microsoft's website https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774).

I don't know what directory that is.

For reference the connection parameters are:

```
Database = Scrap
Schema = dbo
Table = emails
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the question here??? I think you are asking what directory??? We couldn't possibly know. Look at the text "the directory where you want the driver installed". Where do you want it?

Comment: That's what I'm saying, I don't know where I "want" it. Shouldn't there be a standard/default location it goes?

Comment: I don't know about a standard/default location. It seems that you can put it wherever you want. We can't answer that for you.

Comment: Thank you @SeanLange that is an answer. I thought I was missing something but apparently not.